# Cover Page and Title Page with scrbook with unwanted empty page after Title Page

Tags: koma-script, thesis, scrbook, emptypage, bookcover

I am currently writing my thesis and using scrbook document class. I need to get it ready for 2-sided printing with a cover page on top. The printer's requirements are as follows: there needs to be a cover page with no blank page after it and a title page with a blank page after it with every chapter starting on the right side.

I am using this template: https://github.com/fwalch/tum-thesis-latex
Setting srcbook to the two-sided version in that template inserts an empty page after the cover and no empty page after the title while I need the exact opposite. I have searched for it a lot on the internet but in vain.

main.tex has this code:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

% TODO: decide if one-sided/two-sided
\documentclass[titlepage=firstiscover,headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12]{scrbook} % two-sided
% \documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook} % one-sided

% TODO: change citation style in settings
\input{settings}

% TODO: change thesis information
\newcommand*{\getUniversity}{}
\newcommand*{\getFaculty}{}
\newcommand*{\getChair}{}
\newcommand*{\getSchool}{}
\newcommand*{\getTitle}{}
\newcommand*{\getTitleGer}{}
\newcommand*{\getAuthor}{}
\newcommand*{\getDoctype}{Master's Thesis}
\newcommand*{\getSupervisor}{}
\newcommand*{\getAdvisor}{}
\newcommand*{\getSubmissionDate}{}
\newcommand*{\getSubmissionLocation}{}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{−}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

% Set page numbering to avoid "destination with the same identifier has been already used" warning for cover page.
% (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Problems_with_Links_and_Pages).
\pagenumbering{alph}
\input{pages/cover}
\frontmatter{}
\input{pages/title}
\input{pages/disclaimer}
\input{pages/acknowledgments}
\input{pages/abstract}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\tableofcontents{}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\mainmatter{}

\input{chapters/01_introduction}
\appendix{}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}

\addchap{Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
    \itemsep-.25\baselineskip
    \acro{PDE}[PDE]{Partial Differential Equation}
    % TODO: add acronyms
\end{acronym}

\listoffigures{}
\listoftables{}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

settings.tex:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  url=true,
  style=alphabetic,
  maxnames=4,
  minnames=3,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex} % TODO: adapt citation style
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % hidelinks removes colored boxes around references and links
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle=\getTitle,
        pdfauthor=\getAuthor,
    }
}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\addto\extrasamerican{
    \def\lstnumberautorefname{Line}
    \def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}
    \def\sectionautorefname{Section}
    \def\subsectionautorefname{Subsection}
    \def\subsubsectionautorefname{Subsubsection}
}

\addto\extrasngerman{
    \def\lstnumberautorefname{Zeile}
}

% Themes
\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{dark}}{\jobname}}{%
  % Dark theme
  \newcommand{\bg}{black} % background
  \newcommand{\fg}{white} % foreground
  \usepackage[pagecolor=\bg]{pagecolor}
  \color{\fg}
}{%
  % Light theme
  \newcommand{\bg}{white} % background
  \newcommand{\fg}{black} % foreground
}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} % use serif font for headings
\linespread{1.05} % adjust line spread for mathpazo font

% Add table of contents to PDF bookmarks
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
```

cover.tex:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  % HACK for two-sided documents: ignore binding correction for cover page.
  % Adapted from Markus Kohm's KOMA-Script titlepage=firstiscover handling.
  % See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrkernel-title.dtx,
  % \maketitle macro.
  \oddsidemargin=\evensidemargin\relax
  \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\evensidemargin-2in\relax
  \hsize=\textwidth\relax

  \centering
  \thispagestyle{empty}

  \IfFileExists{logos/tum-\fg.pdf}{%
    \includegraphics[height=20mm]{logos/tum-\fg.pdf}
  }{%
    \vspace*{20mm}
  }

  \vspace{5mm}
  {\huge\MakeUppercase{School of \getSchool{}} \par}

  \vspace{5mm}
  {\large\MakeUppercase{\getUniversity{}} \par}

  \vspace{15mm}
  {\Large \getDoctype{} in \getChair{} \par}

  \vspace{10mm}
  {\huge\bfseries \getTitle{} \par}

  \vspace{10mm}
  {\LARGE \getAuthor{}}

  \IfFileExists{logos/faculty-\fg.pdf}{%
    \vfill{}
    \includegraphics[height=20mm]{logos/faculty-\fg.pdf}
  }{}
\end{titlepage}
```

title.tex:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering

  \IfFileExists{logos/tum-\fg.pdf}{%
    \includegraphics[height=20mm]{logos/tum-\fg.pdf}
  }{%
    \vspace*{20mm}
  }

  \vspace{5mm}
  {\huge\MakeUppercase{School of \getSchool{}} \par}

  \vspace{5mm}
  {\large\MakeUppercase{\getUniversity{}} \par}

  \vspace{20mm}
  {\Large \getDoctype{} in \getChair{} \par}

  \vspace{15mm}
  {\huge\bfseries \getTitle{} \par}

%  \vspace{7.5mm}
%  {\huge\bfseries \foreignlanguage{ngerman}{\getTitleGer{}} \par}

  \vspace{15mm}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Author:          & \getAuthor{}         \\
    Supervisor:      & \getSupervisor{}     \\
    Advisor:         & \getAdvisor{}        \\
    Submission Date: & \getSubmissionDate{} \\
  \end{tabular}

  \IfFileExists{logos/faculty-\fg.pdf}{%
    \vfill{}
    \includegraphics[height=20mm]{logos/faculty-\fg.pdf}
  }{}
\end{titlepage}
```

disclaimer.tex:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{0.8\textheight}
\noindent
I confirm that this \MakeLowercase{\getDoctype{}} is my own work and I have documented all sources and material used.

\vspace{15mm}
\noindent
\getSubmissionLocation{}, \getSubmissionDate{} \hspace{50mm} \getAuthor{}

\cleardoublepage{}
```

acknowledgements.tex:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{20mm}

\begin{center}
    {\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section} Acknowledgments}
\end{center}

\vspace{10mm}

%TODO: Acknowledgments

\cleardoublepage{}
```

abstract.tex:

```
\chapter{\abstractname}

%TODO: Abstract
```

01_introduction.tex:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

Please let me know if there is any good idea to achieve this.

Comment: FYI, I added „unwanted“ to your title.

Comment: Welcome, could you provide a short Minimal Working Example which reproduces your unwanted output. That would make it much easier for other users to debug your problem. Nobody likes clicking through links and collect all needed packages/templates by themselves.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I wanted an empty page after the title page and not after the cover page. That makes the current title inaccurate IMO

Comment: @lukeflo, I put the code in the post. Is it good now?

Comment: Its good that your code is there, but its way to long. *Minimal* Working Example means stripping your document of all unecessary stuff that only the needed parts for reproduction remain. Bodytext, if needed, can be filled with blindtext. Take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/297560) how to accomplish that.

Comment: @vikaskurapati, ok: please post a more approrpriate subject here as comment and I will replace it.